# python read csv file as dictionary and sort and increment a counter

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I hope someone point me in the right direction. From what I've read, I believe using a dictionary would best suit this need but I am by no means a master programmer and I hope someone can shed some light and give me a hand. This is the CSV file I have:

```
11362672,091914,100914,100.00,ITEM,11,N,U08
12093169,092214,101514,25.00,ITEM,11,N,U10
12162432,091214,101214,175.00,ITEM,11,N,U07
11362672,091914,100914,65.00,ITEM,11,N,U08
11362672,091914,100914,230.00,ITEM,11,N,U08
```

I would like to treat the first column a key, and the following columns as the values for that key in order to:

1. sort the data by the key
2. counter the occurrences
3. append the counter

This is the output I would like to attain:

```
1,11362672,091914,100914,100.00,ITEM,11,N,U08 # occurrence 1 for key: 11362672
2,11362672,091914,100914,65.00,ITEM,11,N,U08 # occurrence 2 for key: 11362672
3,11362672,091914,100914,230.00,ITEM,11,N,U08 # occurrence 3 for key: 11362672
1,12093169,092214,101514,25.00,ITEM,11,N,U10 # occurrence 1 for key: 12093169
1,12162432,091214,101214,175.00,ITEM,11,N,U07 # occurrence 1 for key: 12162432
```

I need to keep the integrity of each line which is why I think a dictionary will work best. I don't have much, but this is what I started with. This is where I need help to sort, counter and append the counter.

```
import csv
with open('C:/Download/item_report1.csv', 'rb') as infile:
     reader = csv.reader(infile)
     dict1 = {row[0]:row[1:7] for row in reader}
     print dict1
```

gives me:

```
{
'11362672': ['091914', '100914', '230.00', 'ITEM', '11', 'N'], 
'12093169': ['092214', '101514', '25.00', 'ITEM', '11', 'N'], 
'12162432': ['091214', '101214', '175.00', 'ITEM', '11', 'N']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, you should use a counter to tally the keys and a list to store the rows.

As you read in the csv, keep track of how many times you've seen the key value, inserting it into the start of each row as you read them.

Once you've read the file in, you can sort it by the key value first and the occurrence counter second.

```
import csv

counter = {}
data = []

with open('report.csv','rb') as infile:
  for row in csv.reader(infile):
    key = row[0]
    if key not in counter:
      counter[key] = 1
    else:
      counter[key] += 1
    row.insert(0,counter[key])
    data.append(row)

for row in sorted(data,key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0])):
  print row
```

Here's the same thing again, written slightly differently and 4 spaces in accordance with official style guides rather than my personal preference of two.

```
import csv

# key function for sorting later
def second_and_first(x):
    return (x[1],x[0])

# dictionary to store key_fields and their counts
counter = {}
# list to store rows from the csv file
data = []

with open('report.csv','rb') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        # For convenience, assign the value of row[0] to key_field
        key_field = row[0]
        # if key_field is not in the dictionary counter. Add it with a value of 1
        if key_field not in counter:
            counter[key_field] = 1
        # otherwise, it is there, increment the value by one.
        else:
            counter[key_field] += 1
        # insert the value associated with key_field in the counter into the start of
        # the row
        row.insert(0,counter[key_field])
        # Append the row to 
        data.append(row)

for row in sorted(data,key=second_and_first):
    print row
```

Comment: i understand everything up until `sorted(data,key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))` needless to say the above code works and i have some lambda reading to do. thank you very much, you are a genius

Comment: You are welcome, though I have different criteria for declarations of genius. The sorted function takes a keyword function argument of "key" which is applied once to each element of the iterable to create the key to use in comparisons. When I'm not on a phone, I'll write it out as a function definition

Comment: sounds good Matt, the company upgraded machines but no software so ive been writing my own programs but i was definitely stuck here. life saver for sure.

Comment: question, howcome you did not add `row.insert(0, counter[key])` and `data.append(row)` to both the `if` and `else` statement? i get the same output using both methods btw. could the row be compromised by waiting until the `IF/ELSE` is complete to then insert the counter and append row to data list? just thinking outloud here.. -thanks

Comment: In which case you didn't quite understand everything up to the `sorted`. The `row.insert` and `data.append` are out of the `if/else` block and will be executed regardless of which part of the `if/else` is followed.

Comment: for the counter part I would recommend using a `defaultdict`
like:
`from collections import defaultdict;

counter = defaultdict(int);

counter[row[0]] += 1;`

Comment: @JanZeiseweis: I was deliberately keeping this simple.

Comment: @MattH you're right about the if/else block, an over sight on my end. i did some printing of `counter` and `counter[key]` aswell as some lambda functions and i can visually picture how both work. it easier for me to learn how the program works by printing the results. you are great. thank you sir